# Use webrtc or Peer to Peer for video calling IOS and android

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming, webrtc

I want to create the application with Webrtc which will work on website, mobile ios application and android application.

I had found this link :-http://xsockets.net/api/net-c/custom-webrtc-controller

How do I able to create the webrtc in ios application.
Is there any way? 
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenTok](http://tokbox.com/opentok/webrtc/docs) has a native iOS SDK on WebRTC, which should be a good place for you to look into.

Comment: OpenTok is not completely free!

Answer (score 9):

I have been working in this space for the past few months now and webrtc on iOS is not easy.  To help this problem I have added a github repo with a working example of and iOS app using webrtc.

https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios

The site references the google code site as well, so it should be a helpful starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.will check that.Are you successfully able achevie webrtc in ios?

Comment: Yes, the example above works for iOS devices. The simulator does not support video (at least that is my understanding), so I focused on the device solution only.  Hope it helps

Comment: Have you been able to test it on an iPhone 4 or 4s? I've been struggling for days, the video rendering is VERY slow on these devices. But I don't know if that's because I'm doing something wrong or because the capabilities of these devices are not enough. Help please!

Answer (score 7):

I've spend 2 days to research about WebRTC for mobile. I try to install webRTC for Android (follow webrtc.org) but it's too complicated. I just found 2 awesome project:

For server: https://github.com/pchab/ProjectRTC

For Android Client: https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC

Less than 15 minutes to install and it worked well.

About Client iOS, I think you should try gp-coder suggestion, use https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios.

Comment: I followed the instruction but i am not able tor run it. I just see the black screen on android and also when i try to hit "http://localhost:3000" on browser "no page found" . Can you help me here? Actually i want to stream between two android devices using this, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Before run server code, you must install node.js, you can download from here: http://nodejs.org/

Comment: yes i have followed the instruction, every this is setup i have also started the server using "npm start"

Comment: What's your OS? When "npm start" -> what does terminal response? Please make sure Node.js already installed in your PC. You can check Node.js version by command: npm -v.

Comment: I am using widows. when i start a command it look like this http://postimg.org/image/6avhoos5v/. I am uinsg node.js 1.4.28

Comment: Now i am able to run it but how can i achieve peer to peer stream between two android devices. Right now what i am doing is opening my server address in other browser to see the stream of other device. Do i need to use two server ?

Comment: You don't need to use two server. When you open app in 1st-Android-Device, a dialog show to invite other friend, you can send invite via Email, Google hangout, Viber, etc. 2nd-Android-Device (already installed AndroidRTC) just click URL received from 1st Android.